# Did anybody film Feynman's explanation of Bell's Theorem?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, specific-reference, bells-inequality

About 40 years ago, Feynman presented a physics colloquium at MIT. I was there. His main talk was pretty forgettable (even geniuses have off days), but when he finished early he said "OK, let me give you the 5 minute explanation of Bell's Theorem". It was a revelation: I had studied the proof, and understood it as abstract mathematics, but Feynman's presentation showed me how to understand it as concrete physics. No equations, just drawings of rotating pies.

I'm pretty sure MIT didn't film it, but perhaps he gave the same presentation elsewhere and somebody did. Does anyone know?

Comment: How about spinning Derek Mullers? - [Quantum Entanglement & Spooky Action at a Distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuvK-od647c)

Comment: @mmesser314 I found Feynman's pies (representing arbitrary plans for arbitrary experiments) easier to understand than the discrete case in the video. Analog versus digital, maybe.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWTbtXgqYMo&t=1500s

Comment: @annav That was apparently from before Aspect's Experiment. In the video, Feynman is arguing that Bell's Theorem, in the absence of any experiment, does not contribute to understanding of QM. On the other hand, he seems to have (sensibly) appreciated it better once it had been falsified by experiment.

Comment: @annav In this video Feynman is asserting the thing I often say: "no experiment, no physics". Once there was an experiment, he changed his attitude.